# Sencha Touch 2 "TouchStyle" Example

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am working with this example to try and learn Sencha Touch. I have what should be a very simple request, but I am stumped. Does anyone know how to remove the empty category on the home screen (middle of top row, or second from the left)? I have been combing through the code and cannot figure out where this is being configured.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/touchstyle/index.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to inspect the elements with Chrome/Safari Developer Tools? If you had, you would get the simple solution instantly. However, here is the the css which is making that extra space:

```
body:not(.x-phone).x-landscape .categories-list.root 
.categories-list-item:first-child {
    margin-right: 345px;
}
```

Make it margin-right: 0px; and it will work.